# I am trying to hit https URL(json url),s through Python code .But facing AttributeError

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, openssl

I am trying to hit the Secured json URL's for fetching the data by passing the required certificates.
         =====================================

class HTTPSClientAuthHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
    def **init**(self, key, cert):
        urllib2.HTTPSHandler.**init**(self)
        self.key = key
        self.cert = cert

```
def https_open(self, req):
    return self.do_open(self.getConnection, req)

def getConnection(self, host, timeout=300):
    return httplib.HTTPSConnection(host, key_file=self.key, cert_file=self.cert)
```

opener = urllib2.build_opener(HTTPSClientAuthHandler('Certificates/xyz_key_no_phrase.pem', 'Certificates/xyz_cert.pem') )

```
============================================================
```

But while running the script on server(UNIX)[Python 2.6.2] I am facing the **"AttributeError"** as below.

```
============================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./PRODandUAT_URL_https.py", line 12, in <module>
    class HTTPSClientAuthHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSHandler
===============================================================
```

When I am running the  script on my local machine(Python 2.7) it is running absolutely fine.
Is it the issue with python version or some other issue.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance,

Kshitij Dasture.

Comment: Could you please post the first 12 lines of code in your file? That would help a lot to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that for Python 2.6 you need to separately install `ssl` module (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl), try:

1. `pip install ssl` (if you have `pip` installed)
2. Rerun your code